# Can you look at a Bonus Marker before placing it on the board?

Tags: hansa-teutonica

In [Hansa Teutonica](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/43015/hansa-teutonica), I know that for the initial three golden Bonus Markers (I *think* that's the right term for the English version), you place them on the specified beginning locations face down, then flip them up. When you claim a route and take the Bonus Marker that is on that route, you immediately draw one from the pile of Bonus Markers, where they lay face down.

Are you allowed to look at the Bonus Marker before you place it on a new route on the board? Our group couldn't find anything in the rules explicitly addressing this, so we've been playing under the assumption that we're allowed to look at it before deciding where we want to place it, but I'd like some confirmation, as it would impact tactical play.

We're playing the Dutch version (Hanzesteden), in case that may account for a missed translation or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My group has always played that you could look, but while digging through the rulebook to support that decision, I've come to the conclusion that the opposite is true and that you **cannot** look.

[From the English rules:](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/5e9p31d23o/Hansa_Teutonica_English_Rules_%28Revised_1.6%29.pdf?)

> For each bonus marker a player obtains during his turn, he should draw
>   a new bonus marker from the supply and **put it face down on the tin
>   plate on his player mat without looking at it**. Before the next player
>   starts his turn, these bonus marker(s) should be placed next to any
>   route(s) of the player’s choice that meet the following three
>   conditions: (i) no bonus marker is already on that trade route, (ii)
>   no resource is located on that trade route (i.e., all fields need to
>   be empty) and (iii) there is at least one available (i.e. open) Office
>   space in an adjacent city to the route.

You could still argue it's up for debate since it doesn't explicitly state that you cannot look at it before placing it, but based on the fact that you can't look at it when you receive it, and it never states that you *can* look at it, I think the implied answer is that no, you cannot look.